# Python function repeatable logic - how to pass argument that is not string

Tags: python

```
def bulk_save_coordinates():
    index = 0
    coordinates_list = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        coordinates = Coordinates(latitude=all_location_coordinates[index], location_id=index + 1, longitude=all_location_coordinates[index])
        coordinates_list.append(coordinates)
        index += 1

    session.add_all(coordinates_list)
    session.commit()

def bulk_save_timezones():
    index = 0
    timezones_list = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        timezones = Timezone(offset=all_location_coordinates[index], location_id=index + 1, description=all_location_coordinates[index])
        timezones_list.append(timezones)
        index += 1

    session.add_all(timezones_list)
    session.commit()
```

That is my function. I need to use bulk_save_something a lot.

I see that the logic repeats itself there, it is the same pattern. I would like to put in function args something that will not be a string.

Maybe someone have an idea how to change that?

Comment: [Using *args maybe ?](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs#:~:text=Python%20has%20*args%20which%20allow,to%20pass%20variable%20length%20arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a more generic function by sending the changing parameter (here the Coordinates/Timezone class ?)

```
def bulk_save(obj_class):
    index = 0
    obj_list = []
    for element in range(count_indexes()):
        objs = obj_class(offset=all_location_coordinates[index], location_id=index + 1, description=all_location_coordinates[index])
        obj_list.append(objs)
        index += 1

    session.add_all(obj_list)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: It works! :) I think now how to get to class Table columns? offset=all_location_coordinates[index] -> offset is a table column name as the same as location_id and description

Comment: Another question: this part of code **latitude=all_location_coordinates[index]** that is a function that create a list of all latitudes (about 1000 elements). Is there some way to change bulk_save function to be more flexible?

Comment: first, how comes offset and latitude take the same values (all_location_coordinates[index]) ?

Comment: I am sorry. 
I abandoned this function. Because I wanted to insert data into the database table by table instead of record by record. I did it another way. But thanks a lot for a help!